# Deploy desde gitlab a mi servidor

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-commit

Tengo un repositorio git en local que acabo de subir a un repositorio privado en **gitlab**.

En local he estado trabajado con gitflow, tengo creado la rama develop y sobre ella hacia features y las integraba luego en develop.

El siguiente paso ha sido configurar el repositorio remoto con la instrucción
**git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/mi-usuario/repositorio-de-pruebas.git**

Y he hecho mi primer push con el comando **git push**

Y todo lo que hago en develop y hago push se me sube a la rama remota de develop. (hasta aquí todo bien)

Ahora mi pregunta es cual seria la mejor forma de hacer los deploys des del repositorio hasta el servidor que tengo.

Des del mismo gitlab? Debo mirarme el apartado CI de gitlab?

El proyecto esta programado en lenguaje php con el framework Laravel e incluye algo de typescript. El servidor donde quiero hacer el deploy es un S.O Linux

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje está programado el proyecto? ¿Es un proyecto en un lenguaje que necesita un paso de compilación previa antes del despliegue tales como Java o TypeScript? ¿En qué servidor vas a desplegar? ¿Puedes dar más detalles del entorno donde vas a desplegar: sistema operativo, etc.?

Comment: Es un servidor con linux donde voy a hacer el deploy. Es un proyecto con Laravel (php) pero contiene Typescript efectivamente.

Comment: Tendrias que utilizar CI/CD de Gitlab, tendrias unos stages algo como, Buil. Test, ArtifactUpload, Deploy. .. ya en el stage deploy podrias configurar para  conectarte a tu server via ssh y descargar los artefactos y desplegarlos en tu server, todo automaticamente .. Ya con eso podrias hacer que desplegue en tu server automaticamente, cuando realices una actualizaicon de tu codigo o algo así.

Answer (score 1):

Desde Gitlab hay un apartado en tu proyecto que dice Envoriments, pícale ahí y luego en " Read more about environments." ahí tendrás toda la información que ocupas para hacer el CD desde Gitlab